# Which one is faster? `array.findIndex` vs `array.reduce` + `object[index]`

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, indexof

I have client side application in React Native. This app consume server REST API.

This is example of data from API:

Groups:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"example1",
      "items":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"example1",
      "items":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"example1",
            "example":123
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am saving this data into Redux store to have access to them later.

I need to preform many operations with this data, for example: `deleteGroup`,`findGroup`,`deleteItem`,`findItem`, ...
**All those operations are by ID.**

My question is, what is fastest approach to search for values by ID.

I see 3 options:

1. Convert **array of objects** into **object of objects** on backend and then use **object[id]** to access item (heavy on backend)
2. Convert **array of objects** into **object of objects** on client and then use **object[id]** to access item (heavy on client)
3. Use `array.findIndex(i => i.id == 3)` on client

Is `array.findIndex` faster than converting array into object with id keys?
Is there another option how to achieve same, but faster?

Comment: Any processing you can offload to the front-end will reduce the load on your server. Any processing you can do before the browser receives the data makes rendering the page faster... Where is your bottleneck? Is there even a bottleneck or noticeable difference?

Comment: [Mandatory link to Eric Lippert on performance](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Cerbrus I am not sure right now, because there is not enough data to start seeing bottlenecks, but it will occur surely. My question is more about if is good to convert arrays to objects (big amount of pre-processing) or just use `findIndex` on array and have no pre-processing

Comment: If you have a ton of accesses by id, then the fastest approach is to not use the array at all, but instead create a dictionary that references the objects by id.

Comment: @Baterka there is no silver bullet for performance issues. There is no one-size-fits-all solution. It's probably impossible to say what is going to be better without knowing pretty much anything about the data. Are you going to have up to 10 objects? 100? 100 000? Are you going to do more lookups or more inserts and deletes? These all will influence which solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one is faster?

It depends, so I can't answer that. But [you can](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Follow that link, read that article. I just wanted to add some considerations to this exact case. Four questions:

A) Is "object of objects" or "array of objects" shorter to represent in JSON (and thus faster to transfer to the client)? Keep in mind that a lot of clients have a very limited bandwith, so *loading time is a feature*. If it loads faster, more people can use it.

B) Can you share the result of that computation between different clients? In that case, moving the computation to the server might make more sense (if that doesn't conflict with A too much).

C) How *often* do you actually look up an object by id on one page load? Turning an array into a lookup structure is usually O(n), but heavier (memory gets allocated, hashes get computed), while a search is fast and O(n) too. A map lookup is O(1) though, so the more lookups you do, the more likely it gets that the lookup structure is more efficient. Also the more elements you have, the more efficient the lookup gets compared to the search. Going through 10 elements might be faster than computing a hash and looking that up, so for small datasets hashtables might never be more efficient.

```
  lookupEfficiency = timeToBuildTable * n + numberOfLookups * lookupCost * 1;
  arrayEfficiency = numberOfLookups * n * searchCost;
```

D) Do you have unused server resources (and do you pay per instance or usage based) ? If yes, moving the computation to the server has *no cost*, otherwise you should consider moving those to the client as the *client is for free*. Also: Which one is faster? The average client or your server?

As you can see, there is neither a clear answer for "which one is faster?" nor for "which one is better?". Ask yourself the questions above, get some data (*test it!*), then  fell a decision.